# Remove box around collapsed regions and summaries in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-organization

I'm using VS2010 and I'd like to change the font style of regions and/or summaries when they are condensed, primarily to remove the border around these sections as it's becoming distracting when scrolling through the code.

I've looked through the "Fonts and Colors" and other options and couldn't find anything obvious that would let me change it.  Is this font customizable and where can it be done if it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the font color under `Fonts and Colors > Text Editor > Collapsed Text`. Not sure if you can remove the border.

Comment: It doesn't look like the box can be removed, but it does take on the color the text is changed to.  I lightened it up a bit and now it's not distracting, thanks!